# Dataset inserts odd child records

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dataset, transactionscope

**The scenery**: A dataset with a main and two child tables (Sales, SalesDetail, Payments), working with SQL Server 2008 r2, on a Windows Server 2012. This dataset calls a different stored procedure for each insert, update and delete operation, on each table.

**The error**: This routine works fine except that once in a while it: a)inserts child records that are not in the original data table or b) inserts repeated child records.

I've noticed that this error happens when I restore the production database into my development machine, then I run the app and the first transaction gets several details records that weren't the ones I typed. Second time I restore that Database, the error doesn't happen.

The SQL Server logs show some deadlocking when saving these transactions, but those are rare.

The routine for updating is:

(Thanks to Bonnie for this advice on transactions:
[geek-goddess-bonnie.blogspot.mx](http://geek-goddess-bonnie.blogspot.mx/2010/12/transactionscope-and-sqlserver.html))

```
namespace SalesWinCS
{
    class Class1
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        public int UpdateSales(dsetSales ds)
        {
        Int32 _newId = 0;
        SqlDataAdapter da = null;
        SqlDataAdapter daDetail = null;
        using (TransactionScope scope = Utils.GetTransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                // preparing adapters
                da = getDA2updateSales(conn);
                daDetail = getDA2updateSalesDetail(conn);
                // prepare deleted, changed or added tables
                DataTable DeletedDetail = ds.SalesDetail.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
                DataTable AddedDetail = ds.SalesDetail.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
                DataTable ModifiedDetail = ds.SalesDetail.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
                // delete rows
                if ((DeletedDetail != null))
                    daDetail.Update(DeletedDetail);
                // main row
                da.Update(ds, "Sales");
                // get new ID
                _newId = ds.Sales[0].IdSale;
                // updates Detail rows
                if ((ModifiedDetalle != null))
                    daDetail.Update(ModifiedDetail);
                // add new rows
                if ((AddedDetail != null))
                {
                    foreach (dsetSales.SalesDetailRow d in AddedDetail.Rows)
                    {
                        d.IdSale = _newId;
                    }
                    daDetail.Update(AddedDetail);
                }
                // payment table processed as above
                scope.Complete();
                ds.AcceptChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _newId = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Close();
            }
            return _newId;
        }
    }

private SqlDataAdapter getDA2updateSales(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE IdSale = @IdSale ", conn);
        // prepare commands
        da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("spd_Sales", conn);
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("spi_Sales", conn);
        da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("spu_Sales", conn);

        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");

        da.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdClient", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdClient");
        // other fields...
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@new_id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdVenta").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        //
        da.UpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdClient", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdClient");
        // other fields...
        da.DeleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");

        da.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
        da.InsertCommand.CommandTimeout = 900;
        da.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 900;
        return da;
    }

private SqlDataAdapter getDA2updateSalesDetail(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SalesDetail WHERE IdSale = @IdSale", conn);
        // prepare commands
        da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("spd_SaleDetail", conn);
        da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("spi_SaleDetail", conn);
        da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("spu_SaleDetail", conn);

        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");

        da.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSaleDetail", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSaleDetail");
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdProducto", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdProduct");
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Money, 0, "Qty");
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Money, 0, "Cost");
        // other fields
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@new_id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSaleDetail").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        //
        da.UpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSaleDetail", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSaleDetail");
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSale", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSale");
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdProducto", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdProduct");
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Money, 0, "Qty");
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Money, 0, "Cost");
        // ...
        //
        da.DeleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@IdSaleDetail", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "IdSaleDetail");

        da.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
        da.InsertCommand.CommandTimeout = 900;
        da.UpdateCommand.CommandTimeout = 900;
        return da;
    }

public class Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The TransactionScoope that gets returned here is Required and IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TransactionScope GetTransactionScope()
    {
        return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions(){IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted});
    }
}
}
```